# Криптопро cases - получить тип хеша из отсоединенной подписи

Tags: php, криптография, криптопро

Чтоб выполнить VerifyHash нужно получить HashedData. Это получаю из оригинального файла. Но чтоб не полагаться на распространенный вариант, а использовать правильный - нужно получить алгоритм хеша из подписи. Желательно сделать это средствами cades. Как?

Язык не важен, переведу на пхп сам если что.

Достал подписантов, но в атрибутах нет ничего такого

```
$sig='......'

$sd = new CPSignedData();
$sd->VerifyCades($sig,CADES_BES,0); // ошибка, но 
$signers = $sd->get_Signers();
$signer = $signers->get_Item(0);
```